# Prove $a_{n+1} = \frac{4+3 a_n}{3+2 a_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: cauchy-sequences

How to prove that a sequence $a_n$ as defined $a_{n+1} = \frac{4+3 a_n}{3+2 a_n}$ is a Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Hey, just formatting your post. Is it $a_{n+1}$ or $a_n+1$?

Comment: This sequence isn't defined until you specify $a_0$

Comment: That is correct. What is $a_0$?

Comment: @MPW:  Doesn't matter, as long as it's not $-3/2$.

Comment: ^What if $a_0 = -\dfrac{17}{12}$, or $a_0 = -\dfrac{99}{70}$, or $a_0 = -\dfrac{577}{408}$, or ...?

Comment: @JimmyK4542:  You get exactly the same limit, with some negative initial values.  Oh, wait...  Update that to "as long as it's not $-3/2$ or $-\sqrt{2}$ (the negative fixed point)".

Comment: If $a_0 = -\dfrac{17}{12}$, then $a_1 = -\dfrac{3}{2}$, and $a_2$ is undefined. Similarly, if $a_0 = -\dfrac{99}{70}$, then $a_1 = -\dfrac{17}{12}$, $a_2 = -\dfrac{3}{2}$, and $a_3$ is undefined.

Comment: Thank you all for the quick responds ... a_1 = 1 is given and {a_n} is a sequence of real numbers where all n belongs to Z+

Comment: Just a suggestion, you might want to edit your question to include those details.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $-\sqrt{2} < a_0 < \sqrt{2}$.

You can show that $-\sqrt{2} < x < \dfrac{4+3x}{3+2x} < \sqrt{2}$ for all $x \in (-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$.

So, $-\sqrt{2} < a_n < a_{n+1} < \sqrt{2}$ for all $n$, and thus $\{a_n\}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ is increasing and bounded above.

What does this tell you? If $a_0 \not\in (-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, you can still use a similar method.